# Sphinxsearch index min_stemming_len

Tags: search, sphinx

Here is my sphinx search configuration (sphinxsearch_0.9.9-6_amd64):

```
index FULL
{
    charset_type            =       utf-8
    source                  =       FULL
    path                    =       /var/sphinx/data/Full
    docinfo                 =       extern
    mlock                   =       0
    min_stemming_len        =       1
    min_prefix_len          =       1
    min_word_len            =       1
    html_strip              =       1
    index_exact_words       =       1
```

}

```
searchd
{
    listen                  =       192.168.2.3
    log                     =       /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log               =       /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    read_timeout            =       3
    client_timeout          =       60
    max_children            =       30
    pid_file                =       /var/run/searchd.pid
    max_matches             =       1000
    seamless_rotate         =       1
    preopen_indexes         =       0
    unlink_old              =       1
    mva_updates_pool        =       1M
    max_packet_size         =       8M
    max_filters             =       256
    max_filter_values       =       4096
}
```

I use php as client

```
$sphinx_client->SetServer('localhost', 9312);
$sphinx_client->SetConnectTimeout(1);
$sphinx_client->SetArrayResult(true);
$sphinx_client->setRankingMode(SPH_RANK_WORDCOUNT);
$sphinx_client->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);
if ($mode == 'all') {
$sphinx_client->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_RELEVANCE, 'category');
} else {
$sphinx_client->setFilter('category', array($this->_filter_category), FALSE);
}
$sphinx_client->SetLimits(0, $this->_limit);
$results = $sphinx_client->Query('"^'.$query.'$"', 'FULL');
```

for example i have those names in index : 
1. Alex
2. Alen
3. George
4. A
5. G

::: When i try to search for simple 1 char string "A" i get Alen / Alex / A and so on.

How can i search based on string length so i can display them in right order like : 
A / Alen / Alex ...

I also get "WARNING: index 'FULL': no morphology, index_exact_words=1 has no effect, ignoring"

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

use an ordinal field ( [str2ordinal](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-attr-str2ordinal) ) , do your normal search , but modify sort mode : switch to extended mode and use a combination like $sphinx_client->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@weight desc , myordinal asc');